# JDBC Driver not found while try to create a connection

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, jdbc, hive

Hive JDBC Code throws exception.I tried using Hive 0.13.0,Hive 1.12.1 and Hive 0.12.0.

But, none of these are creating a connection.

```
package com.cisco.installbase.hiveconnector;

import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import java.sql.Connection;

public class CreateConnection {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(CreateConnection.class);

    private static Connection instance = null;
    static final String drivername = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";

    private CreateConnection() {

        try {
            LOGGER.info("Creating the connection");

            Class.forName(drivername);
            instance = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive://hddev-c01-edge-02:9083/");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error occurred to create connection",e);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static Connection getInstance() {

        LOGGER.info("Connection Instance");
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = (Connection) new CreateConnection();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Exception StackTrace:

> 16/02/11 07:01:46 INFO hiveconnector.CreateConnection: Connection
>   Instance 16/02/11 07:01:46 INFO hiveconnector.CreateConnection:
>   Creating the connection 16/02/11 07:01:46 ERROR
>   hiveconnector.CreateConnection: No suitable driver found for
>   jdbc:hive://hddev-c01-edge-02:9083/ Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: com.cisco.installbase.hiveconnector.Cre
>   ateConnection cannot be cast to java.sql.Connection  at
>   com.cisco.installbase.hiveconnector.CreateConnection.getInstance(Crea
>   teConnection.java:39)
>           at com.cisco.installbase.hiveconnector.CommonDBUtilities.(CommonDBUtilities.java:19)
>           at com.cisco.installbase.hiveconnector.MainApp.(MainApp.java:33)

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        < dependency> <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId> <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId> 
            <version>1.2.1</version> </dependency>
        <dependency>
```

Comment: What version is the hive server? for version 2 you need to use `jdbc:hive2://XXX`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two problems, the first *"No suitable driver found for jdbc:hive://hddev-c01-edge-02:9083/"* means that you either have the wrong driver or the wrong URL for the driver that you loaded.

As you load `org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver`, you are using the [HiveServer2 client](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients#HiveServer2Clients-UsingJDBC), which uses `jdbc:hive2://<host>:<port>` as the connection string (note the **2** in the url).

For the second problem, please look at the exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: **com.cisco.installbase.hiveconnector.CreateConnection** cannot be cast to **java.sql.Connection** at com.cisco.installbase.hiveconnector.CreateConnection.getInstance(Crea teConnection.java:39)

and your code:

```
public static Connection getInstance() {
    LOGGER.info("Connection Instance");
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = (Connection) new CreateConnection();
    }
    return instance;
}
```

You are trying to cast an instance of your own `CreateConnection` class to a `java.sql.Connection`, which it isn't. As it stands your code doesn't make a lot of sense: you are 1) initializing a static field in a constructor, and 2) trying to return said class as a `java.sql.Connection`. As a side note: static, singleton connections to a database are generally a bad idea.

You could fix your code by changing the constructor to a method that returns a `Connection`, but this will still leave you with the bad idea of having a singleton connection object:

```
public class CreateConnection {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(CreateConnection.class);

    private static Connection instance = null;
    static final String drivername = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";

    public static Connection getInstance() {
        LOGGER.info("Connection Instance");
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = createConnection();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private static Connection createConnection() {
        try {
            LOGGER.info("Creating the connection");

            Class.forName(drivername);
            return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://hddev-c01-edge-02:9083/");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error occurred to create connection",e);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```